# Duvida em ativade com POO

Tags: array, c++, orientação-a-objetos

Olá, basicamente o exercício é fazer com que o usuário digite numeros em um array e depois eu tenho que fazer com que o array seja separado em outros 2 : um para pares e outro para impares. Vou deixar o código abaixo, pois não consigo fazer com que os numeros sejam separados.

Como separar eu sei, mas na hora de colocar os numero nos arrays é que da problema. Se alguem puder me ajudar eu agradeceria.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class separar{

    int p[9]; int im[9]; int v[9];

    public:


    int inserir(){

    cout << "Digite os 10 numeros para preencher o vetor" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){

        cout << "Digite o numero da posicao " << i + 1 << " :" << endl;
        cin >> v[i];
        }
    return 0;
    }

    int dividir(){

        for(int i=0; i <10; i++){
            if(v[i] % 2 == 0){
            p[i] = v[i];
            p[i++];
            }
            else{
                im[i] = v[i];
                im[i++];
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int mostrar(){
        cout << "Vetor inicial: " << endl;
        for(int i=0; i <10; i++){

            cout << "[" << v[i] << "]" << endl;
        }
        cout << "Vetor par: " << endl;
        for(int i=0; i <10; i++){

            cout << "[" << p[i] << "]" << endl;
        }
        cout << "Vetor impar: " << endl;
        for(int i=0; i <10; i++){

            cout << "[" << im[i] << "]" << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
};

int main(){
    int v[9];
    int p[9]; int im[9];
    int menu;
    separar vetores;


    while(4){

        cout << "O que deseja fazer: " << endl;
        cout << "1. Inserir elementos." << endl;
        cout << "2. Separar em pares e impares." << endl;
        cout << "3. Visualizar arrays." << endl;
        cout << "4. Sair." << endl;
        cin >> menu;

        switch(menu){

            case 1:
                vetores.inserir();
                break;   

            case 2:
                vetores.dividir();
                break;

            case 3:
                vetores.mostrar();
                break;

            case 4:
                exit(4);
                break;      
    }       
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Boa noite, Gabriel! Edite sua pergunta e inclua uma possível mensagem de erro, assim a solução para o seu problema pode ser agilizada.

Comment: Boa noite, Ivan. O programa compila tudo certinho, o problema é que a separação de pares e impares não acontece, e na hora de mostrar na tela, aparecem numeros aleatórios.

Answer (score 0):

Olá. Consegui resolver o problema, deixarei a solução aqui, para caso alguém precise.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class separar{

int v[9];
int p[9]; 
int q[9];
int k;
int j=0;

public :

int inserir(){
    cout << "Digite os 10 numeros para preencher o vetor" << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){

        cout << "Digite o numero da posicao " << i + 1 << " :" << endl;
        cin >> v[i];
}
}
    int dividir(){
    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
        if(v[i] % 2 == 0){
            p[k] = v[i];
            k++;
        }
        else {
            q[j] = v[i];
            j++;
        }
}   
}

int mostrar(){

    cout << "Vetor inicial: " << endl;
        for(int i=0; i <10; i++){

        cout << "[" << v[i] << "]" << endl;
    }
    cout << "Vetor par: " << endl;
        for(int i=0; i <k; i++){

        cout << "[" << p[i] << "]" << endl;
    }
    cout << "Vetor impar: " << endl;
        for(int i=0; i <j; i++){

        cout << "[" << q[i] << "]" << endl;
    }

}


};




int main(){

separar vetor;
int menu;


while(4){

    cout << "O que deseja fazer: " << endl;
    cout << "1. Inserir elementos." << endl;
    cout << "2. Separar em pares e impares." << endl;
    cout << "3. Visualizar arrays." << endl;
    cout << "4. Sair." << endl;
    cin >> menu;

    switch(menu){

        case 1:
            vetor.inserir();
            break;   

        case 2:
            vetor.dividir();
            break;

        case 3:
            vetor.mostrar();
            break;

        case 4:
            exit(4);
            break;      
}       
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Explique o que havia de errado Gabriel.

Comment: Seria legal comentar onde estava o problema e marcar sua resposta como aceita, assim o assunto fica como "fechado" aqui.